# problemas para interactuar con la base de datos desde un fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, android-fragment

De tanto indagar me di cuenta que los `fragment` no trabajan la relacion con la base de datos `SQLite` como lo hacen las `activity` directamente, dicho esto podrian ayudarme a trabajar o cual es la linea de codigo correcta para poder trabajar con la Base de datos desde el `fragment`

**SQLite.class** (donde tengo la base de datos solo 2 tablas)

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by erny on 27/10/2016.
 */

public class SQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //constructor.......
    public SQLite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }



    //aqui se crea la tabla...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table usuarios (id_usuario integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "usuario text, clave text)");


        db.execSQL("create table profesores (id_profesor integer primary key autoincrement," +
                "nombre_profesor text, comentario_profesor text");


        db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values('0','admin','admin')");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("create table usuarios (id_usuario integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "usuario text, clave text)");


        db.execSQL("create table profesores (id_profesor integer primary key autoincrement," +
                "nombre_profesor text, comentario_profesor text");

        db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values('0','admin','admin')");


    }
}
```

**MenuCentral** (es la actividad donde se desempeña el `fragment` la cual es un `Navigation Drawer`)

```
    package company.viral.organizadorjec;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.AjustesF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.CalendarioF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.ConfiguracionActividadF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.ConfiguracionMateriaF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.ConfiguracionPeriodoF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.ConfiguracionProfesorF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.InicioF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.PerfilF;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.ProfesoresF;

public class MenuCentral extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private PopupWindow popupadicion;
    private DrawerLayout posicionpopup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_central);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        posicionpopup = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);



        //colocamos el fragment con que inicia el menu

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new InicioF()).commit();


        //este es el apartado para el botonsito flotante

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //metodo de escucha para el popup
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //implementamos el popup
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View vistaadicion = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pop_adicion,null);

                popupadicion = new PopupWindow(
                        vistaadicion, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );

                //luego de clicear y abrir el popup le decimos...
                //si das al profe ve a profe
                LinearLayout btnprofe = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarprofesor);
                btnprofe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionProfesorF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //si le das actividad ve actividad
                LinearLayout btnactividad = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregaractividad);
                btnactividad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionActividadF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //si le das a materias ve a materias
                LinearLayout btnmaterias = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarmateria);
                btnmaterias.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionMateriaF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //si le das a periodo ve a periodo
                LinearLayout btnperiodo = (LinearLayout) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarperiodo);
                btnperiodo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionPeriodoF()).commit();
                        popupadicion.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                //luego le decimos que cierre el popup con el boton

                Button cerrarboton = (Button) vistaadicion.findViewById(R.id.btnpopupcerrar);
                cerrarboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        popupadicion.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                //hubicamos donde queremos el popup
                popupadicion.showAtLocation(posicionpopup, Gravity.CENTER,0,0 );
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_central, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new InicioF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ProfesoresF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new CalendarioF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new AjustesF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new PerfilF()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_materia){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor,new ConfiguracionMateriaF()).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**ConfiguracionProfesorF** (`fragment` involucrado en el problema)

```
    package company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import company.viral.organizadorjec.R;
    import company.viral.organizadorjec.SQLite;


    public class ConfiguracionProfesorF extends Fragment {

        private EditText etnombreprofesorf;
        private EditText etcomentarioprofesorf;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_configuracion_profesor, container, false);

            etnombreprofesorf = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etnombreprofesor);
            etcomentarioprofesorf = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etcomentarioprofesor);

            Button btnagrerarpf = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarprofesor);
            btnagrerarpf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String auxnp = etnombreprofesorf.getText().toString();
                    String auxcp = etcomentarioprofesorf.getText().toString();

                    SQLite admin = new SQLite(getActivity(),"administracion",null,1);
                    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();

                    ContentValues registroprofe = new ContentValues();

                    registroprofe.put("nombre_profesor",auxnp);
                    registroprofe.put("comentario_profesor",auxcp);

                    bd.insert("profesores",null,registroprofe);

                    bd.close();

                    etnombreprofesorf.setText("");
                    etcomentarioprofesorf.setText("");

                }
            });


            return view;
        }


    }

**fragment_configuracion_profesor** (correspondiente `layout` de dicho `fragment`)

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="company.viral.organizadorjec.Fragment.ConfiguracionProfesorF">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:text="Registro de Profesores"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            tools:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/etnombreprofesor"
                android:hint="Nombre del profesor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Elija primera caracteristica:"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView8" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Elija segunda caracteristica:"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView11" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner2" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Si lo desea ingrese comentarios del profesor"
                android:id="@+id/etcomentarioprofesor" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:text="Agregar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button" />

            <Button
                android:text="Editar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

De ante mano muchisimas gracias por ayudarme, disculpen el codigo tan noob, pero tengan en cuenta que estoy empezando y es "autodidactico" si poseen ejercicios para aprender a reducir codigo de verdad se los agradeceria de verdad... en fin muchisimas gracias por su tiempo !!!

Comment: Hi Erny , mas tarde entro para continuar lo del proyecto. Pero aquí que problema tienes al usar la BD desde el Fragment, no debería ser diferente a usarla en una Activity.

Comment: es lo mismo que digo... la cuestion esta aqui...

SQLite admin = new SQLite(getActivity(),"administracion",null,1);
SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();

 donde se supone que el codigo original seria...

SQLite admin = new SQLite(this,"administracion",null,1); pero no me deja

Answer (score 1):

Asumiré que estás recibiendo un `NullPointerException` al momento de depurar. Esto se debe a que estás llamando a la actividad en el método `onCreateView()` del fragmento, el cual puede ser llamado incluso cuando la actividad no ha terminado de inicializarse. Por ende, al momento de llamar a `getActivity()` obtienes `null`. Prueba inicializando la instancia de SQLite desde el método `onActivityCreated()`.

Algo de código:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button btnagrerarpf = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnagregarprofesor);
    btnagrerarpf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String auxnp = etnombreprofesorf.getText().toString();
            String auxcp = etcomentarioprofesorf.getText().toString();

            SQLite admin = new SQLite(getActivity(),"administracion",null,1);
            SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues registroprofe = new ContentValues();

            registroprofe.put("nombre_profesor",auxnp);
            registroprofe.put("comentario_profesor",auxcp);

            bd.insert("profesores",null,registroprofe);

            bd.close();

            etnombreprofesorf.setText("");
            etcomentarioprofesorf.setText("");
        }
    });
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

¡Me avisas si funciona!